Orthogonality to simplex-constrained complement
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $V$ be a family of vectors in $\R^d$. Consider the set $$H = \{u\in\R^d\;:\;u_i>0\,,\;\forall i\,;\quad\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^d u_i=1\,;\quad u\cdot v = 0\,,\;\forall v\in V\}\,.$$
In practice, this is the intersection between the simplex and the orthogonal complement to $\mathrm{span}(V)$.
Let $w\in\R^d$ such that $w\cdot u=0$ for all $u\in H$. Is it true that $w\in\mathrm{span}(V)$?
If there was no constraint on the simplex I would say yes with no doubts. Indeed, if $w\neq\mathrm{span}(V)$, then I can write $w = w_0 + w_1$, with $w_0\in\mathrm{span}(V)$, and $w_1$ orthogonal to $V$ and non-zero. Now I would have that $w_1$ is in $H$ (assuming no simplex requirement was there) and $w\cdot w\neq 0$. However, since elements in $H$ have to be in the simplex, in general it is not true that $w\in H$. So I am not sure whether the conclusion still holds...

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
The answer is actually no. Indeed, consider vectors in $\R^3$. let $V = \{(0,1,1)\}$. Then we have that there is one single element in $H$, namely $u = (1,0,0)$. Now $w=(0,1,0)$ is not in the span of $V$ but is orthogonal to $H$.
